# Swing program does not close if while loop is empty, does close however if while loop contains a print

Tags: java, swing

I have encountered a very wierd 'bug' while trying to create a small dialog API using swing (similar to JOptionPane).

Basically you call a method which opens a JFrame, waits until a button was selected and returns it; to wait until a button was selected I use a while loop: `while (isVisible()) {}`. Now the wierd part is that the program won't finish if the loop is empty (as it is here) however if I place a `System.out.print()` inside it will. I tried to place something else inside (like `int i = 0;`) but it does not make a difference.

*EDIT: Using a debugger solves this too even without the print and without breakpoints.*

Since I have no clue what the problem could be I'll post the entire `Dialog` class:

```
package Frame.Dialogs;

import GameEngine.EngineMgr;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Dialog extends JFrame {

public enum Buttons {
    OK(Dialog.OK),
    YES(Dialog.YES),
    RETURN(Dialog.RETURN),
    CONFIRM(Dialog.CONFIRM),
    YES_NO(Dialog.YES, Dialog.NO),
    YES_NO_CANCEL(Dialog.YES, Dialog.NO, Dialog.CANCEL),
    YES_CANCEL(Dialog.YES, Dialog.CANCEL),
    YES_RETURN(Dialog.YES, Dialog.RETURN),
    OK_CANCEL(Dialog.OK, Dialog.CANCEL),
    CONFIRM_CANCEL(Dialog.CONFIRM, Dialog.CANCEL),
    CONFIRM_RETURN(Dialog.CONFIRM, Dialog.RETURN);

    private JButton[] buttons;

    Buttons(JButton... buttons) {
        this.buttons = buttons;
    }

    JButton[] val() {
        return buttons;
    }
}

public static final JButton OK = new JButton("OK");
public static final JButton NO = new JButton("NO");
public static final JButton YES = new JButton("YES");
public static final JButton CANCEL = new JButton("CANCEL");
public static final JButton RETURN = new JButton("RETURN");
public static final JButton CONFIRM = new JButton("CONFIRM");

private static boolean initialized = false;

private JPanel button;
private JPanel content;
private JButton selection;

private Dialog(JPanel panel, String title, Buttons buttons) {
    if (!initialized)
        initialize();

    setTitle(title);
    setIconImage(null);

    button = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
    for (JButton b : buttons.val())
        button.add(b);

    content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
    content.add(panel);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
private JButton display() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c1.gridx = 0;
    c1.gridy = 0;
    c1.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    GridBagConstraints c2 = (GridBagConstraints) c1.clone();
    c2.gridy = 1;

    add(content, c1);
    add(button, c2);
    pack();
    Dimension sc = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLocation((sc.width - getWidth()) / 2, (sc.height - getHeight()) / 2);
    setVisible(true);

    //Strange loop

    //Will get stuck:
    //while (isVisible()) {}

    //Works fine:
    while (isVisible())
        System.out.print("");

    return selection;
}

private void initialize() {
    //JButton[] buttons = new JButton[]{YES, NO, OK, CANCEL, RETURN, CONFIRM};
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[]{OK};
    for (JButton b : buttons) {
        b.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(EngineMgr.getGraphicEngine().get("bt_" + b.getText()).getScaledInstance(150, 84, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        b.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(EngineMgr.getGraphicEngine().get("sBt_" + b.getText()).getScaledInstance(150, 84, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        b.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(EngineMgr.getGraphicEngine().get("pBt_" + b.getText()).getScaledInstance(150, 84, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        b.setText("");
        b.setSize(new Dimension(150, 50));
        b.addActionListener(e -> {
            selection = b;
            dispose();
        });
    }
}

public static JButton showDialog(String msg, String title, Buttons buttons) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
    panel.add(new JLabel(msg));
    return new Dialog(panel, title, buttons).display();
}

public static JButton showDialog(JPanel panel, String title, Buttons buttons) {
    return new Dialog(panel, title, buttons).display();
}

}
```

Also here's the call:

```
JButton selection = Dialog.showDialog("Test 1", "Test", Dialog.Buttons.OK);
if (selection == Dialog.OK)
    System.out.println("OK");
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Don't know why the code behaves different, but the solution is to not even use either code. Don't extend a JFrame for something like this. Instead you use a `modal JDialog`. The modal JDialog automatically blocks until the dialog is closed. No special logic is required. Don't attempt to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @camickr Sorry, not everybody is familiar with the entire swing library, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: An interesting observation, but a bad idea.  `while (isVisible()) {}` will hog the CPU and will block the [AWT event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), preventing windows from being painted and preventing those windows from responding to user input.  Use event handlers to detect changes in component state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly have the `while` loop running outside of the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Use `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` to get on the right thread.

If you do use Swing/AWT with multiple threads (EDT will be the one thread - so don't even use the main thread), then you'll have race conditions and odd things will happen. It's common for `System.out.println` to cause some delay, even with single threaded hardware, causing racy behaviour to change.

When on the EDT, blocking or running a busy loop will cause the UI to freeze. So you'll need an AWT/Swing event handler to send an event back to whatever other thread you have, or start a new task.

Comment: The UI doesn't freeze, it still responds, the loop is just never left even if the dispose of the window still works. And why does a `System.out.print("")` solve this? Btw. I forgot to mention but using a debugger solves it as well even without the print.

Comment: @VoroX well, in first instance you shouldn't be using a `while(true)` loop

Comment: It doesn't freeze because the code is not executing on the EDT. Correct that and it will freeze. / I've added a bit to mention that `print` (or debugging) will disturb the timings.